# Intened to move to Ubuntu

Tags: installation

Does Ubuntu Run without problems on an Intel B980 2.4  sandybridge proccessor in 64 bit mode on a Laptop which has been configured for Windows 8 ?  My concerns are from different forums which describe their computers Hang or Crash

Comment: It will run without installing from a USB stick.  Try it out first - it it runs OK from the USB install.  If not you can ask specific questions about any problems you see.

Answer (score 0):

Your processor does not appear to be official [Ubuntu certified Hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/), but that doesn't mean Ubuntu won't run on it. You may want to do a Google search with your laptop name and "Ubuntu installation" to get tips and tweaks for installation on your specific Laptop. You should [Download Ubuntu x64](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and put it onto usb stick. Boot to the usb stick and select "Try Ubuntu". This will let you run Ubuntu without installing it to your machine. Test it out and make sure everything works. If it works well in this mode, it will probably run well when it is installed. To install double click the "Install Ubuntu" shortcut on the desktop. The Ubuntu installer will step you through the installation of Ubuntu.